# WebBrowserDocumentCompleted не отрабатывает

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser

Получаю список html-файлов с путями к ним и сохраняю их в `List<string>` и `DataGridView`:

```
string[] _files = Directory.GetFiles(delDir, _del);
foreach (string fl in _files)
{
    myList.Add(new StringValue(fl));
}
myDataGridView.DataSource = myList;
```

На `myDataGridView` висит обработчик `SelectionChanged`, который получает имя файла из выделенной строки `myDataGridView` и передает его в объект `WebBrowser` с именем `myWeb`:

```
myWeb.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(myWeb_DocumentCompleted_1);
myWeb.Navigate(new Uri(fileName));
```

Для объекта myWeb установлен обработчик `DocumentCompleted`.В его коде небольшой html-парсер:

```
HtmlDocument doc = myWeb.Document;
HtmlElementCollection tagCollection;
tagCollection = doc.GetElementsByTagName("div");
```

Затем из tagCollection я получаю нужные мне данные и сохраняю их в переменные string.

Т.е. получается схема: получаем путь и имя файла, сохраняем его в строку DataGrid, при выборе строки из DataGrid в WebBrowser загружается html-документ. Как только документ загрузился, срабатывает html-парсер, сохраняющий нужный мне текст или теги.

Но все это работает только если я сам выбираю строки, вручную.
Попытался сделать чтобы строки выбирались сами таким образом:

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in myDataGridView.Rows)
{
    row.Selected = true;
}
```

Строки выбираются, но парсер не срабатывает, поскольку WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted попросту не работает. Или не успевает отработать.
Есть ли выход из ситуации?

Comment: Может быть выбрано несколько строк? Как тогда определяется `filename`?

Comment: Проверял. Строка выделена одна. При первой инициализации всегда первая. FileName берется из (selectedRow.Cells["Value"].Value); выделенной строки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После выбора каждой строки нужно дожидаться пока `WebBrowser` загрузит и отработает страницу.

Для этого можно отслеживать событие `DocumentCompleted` у браузера.

```
//флаг для отслеживания
private bool isCompleted;

void myWeb_DocumentCompleted_1(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //обработка страницы
    //...
    //после обработки устанавливаем флаг
    isCompleted = true;
}

//цикл обработки
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in myDataGridView.Rows)
{
    isCompleted = false;
    row.Selected = true;
    //дожидаемся завершения обработки
    while (!isCompleted)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
}
```

Также из кода неясно зачем при выборе каждой строки привязывать новый обработчик к `DocumentCompleted`. Достаточно одного глобального.

И если задача в данном случае состоит именно в разборе HTML файлов, то, возможно, будет проще использовать html-парсер (например, [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/)) вместо `WebBrowser`. Так можно будет грузить страницы напрямую из файлов без визуального компонента.

Comment: Сторонние парсеры я как раз использовать не хочу. Визуальный компонент как бы и не обязателен, он нужен для отладки. Про глобальный обработчик подумаю. Спасибо.

Comment: isCompleted = true; действительно помог. Благодарю!

Comment: @JackBlack Пожалуйста! Отметьте ответ как принятый, если проблема уже решена.